# Get latest available value for filling missing values in the next rows R

Tags: r

i have table with missing values, how can i fill the next 3 missing values with the latest available value?

as example i use this table, I want to fill 2021 May - 2021 Jul value with the latest non-missing data which is 249.

```
Date        value
2021 Jan    500
2021 Feb    2340
2021 Mar    3000
2021 Apr    249
2021 May    NA
2021 Jun    NA
2021 Jul    NA
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with the `zoo` library:

```
library(zoo)
na.locf(na.locf(df))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is with `fill`:

```
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  fill(value)
```

You could specify the direction in which to fill with `.direction = ...` but "down" is the default so in your case need not be specified